# Integrating second order ODE and finding fixed points

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

We know that fixed points are such points, where $x'$ = $x''$ = $0$.

Let's say we are given second order ODE $:$ $ x'' + sin(x) = C$

We can rewrite it into system of first order ODEs:

$ \begin{cases} x_1' = x_2 \\ x_2' = C - sin(x_1) \end{cases} $

Now, according to this equation fixed points occur at $sin(x_1) = C$

But if we take the first integral of the system we will find that $ \frac {(x_2)^2}{2} - cos(x_1) = C \cdot  x_1 + Constant$

Now, points where $sin(x) = C$ don't satisfy the equation above (phase portrait confirms that). Yet the book claims that the fixed points are arrived from first equation.

Could you help wih my confusion? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding, you have the following system:

$x''(t)+\sin(x(t))=C$

for which you would like to find fixed points, where $x''(t)=x'(t)=0$ for all t, such that $x(t)=x_0$ (i.e., x is a constant function which does not change with t).

You have already pointed out that any fixed point satisfies $\sin(x_0)=C$, and it seems that your confusion stems from attempting to integrate the differential equation with respect to x, done as follows:

$v(t)=x'(t)$

$x''(t)=v'(t)=\frac{dv}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}=v\frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{1}{2}v^2)$

$x''(t)+\sin(x(t))=\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{1}{2}v^2)+\sin(x)=C \implies \frac{1}{2}v^2-\cos(x)=Cx+C_2$, where $C_2$ is a constant of integration.

There are two problems with this. First, in our integration, we cannot integrate by x directly, because x is a function of t. For the $\sin(x)$ term, for example, the integral becomes $\int^{t_1}_{t_0} \sin(x(t))x'(t)\mathrm{d}t$, where we then do a u-sub $u=x(t)$ and complete the integral quite simply. However, a fixed point requires $x'(t)=0$, so our entire integral is 0, and in fact the rigorous integrating process yields the equation 0=0, which does not give us any new information about the system. Second, even if the integration were justified, it still would not be useful. We know that $x'(t)=v(t)=0$, which means our integrated expression becomes:

$\frac{1}{2}v^2-\cos(x)=Cx+C_2 \implies -\cos(x_0)=Cx_0+C_2 \implies C_2=-\cos(x_0)-Cx_0$. We have defined a new constant $C_2$, but we have not learned anything new about $x(t)$ or $x_0$.

In conclusion, your book is right in that $\sin(x)=C$ is the only equation you need to fully describe the fixed points of your system.

Answer (score 4):

The fixed points occur when $\sin(x_1)=C$ and $x_2=0$.   When those conditions are met, $x_1'$ and $x_2'$ are both 0.  I'm placing a streamline plot with C=0.5 below.

[image]

As in Marcus's answer, I get that $U(x(t))= \frac{ x_2^2(t)}2 - C\, x_1(t) - \cos(x_1(t))$ is constant for any solution $x(t)$ of the differential equation (i.e $U(x)= \frac{ x_2^2}2 - C\, x_1 - \cos(x_1)$ is a first integral of the system).  The fixed points of the ODE occur at the *critical points* of $U(x)$ which occur exactly when $\sin(x_1)=C$ *and* $x_2=0$.

Comment: May I ask what program did you use for the streamplot?

Comment: I used Mathematica.  The command was StreamPlot[ {x2, 0.5 - Sin[x1]}, {x1, 0, 3}, {x2, -0.2, 0.2}]